# YARD for keyword arguments with default hash

Tags: ruby, yard, yardoc

I have a method that looks like this:

```
def get_endpoint(params: {})
end
```

I want the caller of this method to be able to pass in a few optional parameters.

I want to write YARD documentation to support this and if I wasn't using keyword arguments I'd use the [`@option`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#option)  declaration.

However, YARD's own docs say:

> Note: For keyword parameters, use @param, not @option.

So I tried:

```
  # @param params [Hash] options to be used in request
  # @param date [String] date in YYYYMMDD
  # @param start_time [Integer] start_time in Epoch
```

That fails because YARD only sees the `params` keyword argument I'm using. The exact failure is:

```
@param tag has unknown parameter name: date
```

So then I tried to use the `@option` syntax replaced with the `param` keyword:

```
  # @param params [Hash] options to be used in request
  # @param params [String] :date in YYYYMMDD
  # @param params [Integer] :start_time in Epoch
```

That results in a different error:

```
@param tag has duplicate parameter name: params
```

Ideally I want to describe the `params` hash with the 3 or 4 options the user of this method can use.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That signature does not use keyword arguments for `:date` or `:start_time`. Keyword arguments for those arguments would be specified as something like:

```
def get_endpoint(date:, start_time:)
```

`@option` is specifically meant for specifying options that would be contained within an options `Hash` in your case `params`. Since you are using a keyword argument for `params` I would recommend adding the `@param` tag for this as well to clearly identify the keyword argument. For Example:

```
@param params [Hash]  options to be used in request
@option params [String] :date in YYYYMMDD
@option params [Integer] :start_time in Epoch
```

[Documentation for `@options`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#option) just in case.

Answer (score 0):

For *actual keywords*, `@param` is what you want to use. Per [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#param):

> ```
> @param name [Types] description
> ```
>
> Documents a single method parameter (either regular or keyword) with a given name, type and optional description.
>
> Example:
>
> ```rb
> # @param url [String] the URL of the page to download
> # @param directory [String] the name of the directory to save to
> def load_page(url, directory: 'pages') end
> ```

NOTE: this answer doesn't answer the question body, but its title, and is first designed for googlers. for disambiguation, see the accepted answer